# If $\int_a^b \left |{f^{\prime}}\right |=V\left. [ a,b \right ]$, $f$ of bounded variation, then $f $ absolutely continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

I need a little help with this.

If $f:\mathbb{\left. [ a,b \right ]}\longrightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ is a function of bounded variation on $\left. [ a,b \right ]$, and if $\int_a^b \left |{f^{\prime}}\right |=V\left. [ a,b \right ]$, where $V\left. [ a,b \right ]$ is the variation of $f$ on $\left. [ a,b \right ]$. Show that $f$ is absolutely continuous on $\left. [ a,b \right ]$

I think this must be easy, but I don't see the way of prove it.
Thanks.